# Salesforce Object which holds "HTML & CSS" records?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, html5

I am quite new to Lightning Development and appreciate any help.
I have a custom object called "template" and the requirement is the following: There are n template records let's say "standard" and "custom1". Each record should contain HTML markup, CSS, scripts and so on (like a webpage). Then there is a second object such as "Recipes". Each recipes has a lookup field to "template" and when a template is assigned to a recipe record the recipe fields should be rendered according to the template markup. I imagine there is something like a custom component on the recipe record which loads the template and the data from the merge fields. I have created both objects and custom field but I do not know how to "store" the html and CSS on the template records?

What would be a good approache to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please let us know what have you tried so far?

Comment: I created a visual force page which uses pure html and merge fields from the recipe object but I can not relate a visual force page to a template record so that it gets rendered when someone opens the template record

Comment: Please check aura:html  where you can insert style attribute to your lightning component or any HTML element you want